# R - transform column type where column name is variable

Tags: r, dataframe

pretty simple question, but I can't find an answer.
Suppose I want to transform data frame column type from string to double, but column name is unknown at compile time, so I can't write like:

```
train <- transform(train, columnName = as.double(columnName))
```

but if I write smth like this

```
varKnownAtRuntime <- "columnName"
train <- transform(train, varKnownAtRuntime = as.double(varKnownAtRuntime))
```

It just appends column "varKnownAtRuntime" to my data frame, while I want to change type of train$columnName

Comment: of course it appends because you assign a character string `"columnName"` to `varKnowAtRutime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` is a non-standard-evaluating shortcut function. If you want to use column names stored in variables you'll need to use standard evaluation functions like `[`.

```
varKnownAtRuntime <- "columnName"
train[, varKnownAtRuntime] = as.double(train[, varKnownAtRuntime])
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  I was going to go with `train[[varKnown]] <- as.double(train[[varKnown]])`.